# How to get text from each cell of an HTML table?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium 2.0, I have no idea how to traverse through a HTML table in a webpage.  In selenium2.0 javadoc, I found two classes "TableFinder" and "TableCellFinder", but I couldn't find any examples.

I want to do something like this:

```
RowCount=Get how many rows are there in the html table

for each row of the table
{
   column_count=Get column count
   for each column
   {
      cell_value=get_text_from(row,col);
      Do something with cell_value
   }
}
```

How can I get the text from each of the table cells?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Thanks for the earlier reply.

I figured out the solutions using selenium 2.0 classes.

```java
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class WebTableExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("http://localhost/test/test.html");      

        WebElement table_element = driver.findElement(By.id("testTable"));
        List<WebElement> tr_collection=table_element.findElements(By.xpath("id('testTable')/tbody/tr"));

        System.out.println("NUMBER OF ROWS IN THIS TABLE = "+tr_collection.size());
        int row_num,col_num;
        row_num=1;
        for(WebElement trElement : tr_collection)
        {
            List<WebElement> td_collection=trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
            System.out.println("NUMBER OF COLUMNS="+td_collection.size());
            col_num=1;
            for(WebElement tdElement : td_collection)
            {
                System.out.println("row # "+row_num+", col # "+col_num+ "text="+tdElement.getText());
                col_num++;
            }
            row_num++;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a C# example I just cooked up, loosely based on the answer using CSS selectors, hopefully of use to others for seeing how to setup a `ReadOnlyCollection` of table rows and iterate over it in MS land at least.  I'm looking through a collection of table rows to find a row with an `OriginatorsRef` (just a string) and a `TD` with an image that contains a title attribute with `Overdue by` in it:

```cs
    public ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> GetTableRows()
    {
        this.iwebElement = GetElement();
        return this.iwebElement.FindElements(By.CssSelector("tbody tr"));
    }
```

And within my main code:

```cs
        ...
        ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> TableRows;
        TableRows = f.Grid_Fault.GetTableRows();

        foreach (IWebElement row in TableRows)
        {
            if (row.Text.Contains(CustomTestContext.Current.OriginatorsRef) &&
              row.FindElements(By.CssSelector("td img[title*='Overdue by']")).Count > 0)
                return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Selenium 2. Selenium 1.x has `selenium.getTable("tablename".columnNumber.rowNumber)` to reach the required cell. May be you can use `webdriverbackedselenium` and do this.

And you can get the total rows and columns  by using

`int numOfRows = selenium.getXpathCount("//table[@id='tableid']//tr")`

```
int numOfCols=selenium.getXpathCount("//table[@id='tableid']//tr//td")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = '';
    for($rowth=0; $rowth<=100; $rowth++){
        $content .= $selenium->getTable("tblReports.{$rowth}.0") . "\n";
        //$content .= $selenium->getTable("tblReports.{$rowth}.1") . "\n";
        $content .= $selenium->getTable("tblReports.{$rowth}.2") . " ";
        $content .= $selenium->getTable("tblReports.{$rowth}.3") . " ";
        $content .= $selenium->getTable("tblReports.{$rowth}.4") . " ";
        $content .= $selenium->getTable("tblReports.{$rowth}.5") . " ";
        $content .= $selenium->getTable("tblReports.{$rowth}.6") . "\n";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another C# example. I just made an extension method for it.

```
public static string GetCellFromTable(this IWebElement table, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        return table.FindElements(By.XPath("./tbody/tr"))[rowIndex].FindElements(By.XPath("./td"))[columnIndex].Text;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

its

`selenium.getTable("tablename".rowNumber.colNumber)`

not

`selenium.getTable("tablename".colNumber.rowNumber)`

Comment: You should have commented this instead of posting it as an answer.