# Is it possible to obtain multiple elements on a page simultaneously from a WebDriver instance?

Tags: java, selenium

The application I am testing has a ton of tables that needs to be parsed constantly. The method I am currently using is slow for very large tables, so i figured I could try multi-thread it and obtain those elements simutaniusly

```
public class TableThread
  implements Runnable
{

  private WebDriver driver;
  private String thread;

  TableThread(WebDriver driver, String thread)
  {
    this.driver = driver;
    this.thread = thread;
  }

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    getTableRow();
  }

  private String getTableRow()
  {
    System.out.println("start getting elements " + thread);

    WebElement tableElement = driver.findElement(By.className("logo"));
    String href = tableElement.getAttribute("href");
    System.out.println("Table Att: " + thread + " " + href);

    return href;

  }

}
```

and the loop that calls that method

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
  TableThread tableThread = new TableThread(driver, "Thread " + i);
  threadExecutor.execute(tableThread);
  Thread.sleep(50);
}
```

Errors when setting this.driver = ThreadGuard.protect(driver);

```
start getting elements
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Thread safety error; this instance of WebDriver was constructed on thread main (id 1) and is being accessed by thread pool-1-thread-1 (id 26)This is not permitted and *will* cause undefined behaviour`
```

Errors with setting this.driver = driver;

```
Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-1" org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Error 404: Not Found
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't do that. [`WebDriver` is not thread-safe.](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_Is_WebDriver_thread-safe?) So this will certainly lead to crazy-unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Okay, so a better approach would probably be to try and cut down the time the css selectors take to obtain a table? Would it be possible to driver.getPageSource and save that, then parse that for the table instead and somehow use the `findElements(By.cssSelector());` to parse the page source that way?

Comment: How slow is 'slow'? Is this *all* the code you are using, which part of is slow?

Comment: It takes about 9 seconds to get a table that has 2 columns, and 5 rows. I am using the solution similar to what is found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198947/how-to-get-text-from-each-cell-of-an-html-table) Also good to note, I am not just getting the table text, but also a few of the values withing the table such as type, class, and name.

Comment: I think givin us a sample table and the code you used can be more productive in finding a good solution.

Comment: Okay, I will have to get some code together and ask that question. Thanks for all the help so far!

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to @acdcjunior's comment that the WebDriver class is not thread safe; I've found the following issue which I believe is related to this question: [Issue 6592: IE Driver returns 404: File not found](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6592)

If it is the same issue you're having, then one solution is to synchronise your calls the WebDriver. I solved this by creating a `SynchronizedInternetExplorerDriver.java` class, which synchronises calls to the underlying WebDriver.

Let me know if this helps (using this SynchronizedInternetExplorerDriver, you'll (at least) be able to rule out thread issues as the cause).

**Code Snippet:**

```
public class SynchronizedInternetExplorerDriver extends InternetExplorerDriver {

...

    @Override
    protected Response execute(String driverCommand, Map<String, ?> parameters) {
        synchronized (getLock()) {
            return super.execute(driverCommand, parameters);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Response execute(String command) {
        synchronized (getLock()) {
            return super.execute(command);
        }
    }

...

}
```

**Full Code:** [SynchronizedInternetExplorerDriver.java](https://gist.github.com/nickgrealy/267fd8016bc84eddeb50)