# How get pagesource of website Similar inspector by c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

i want to get all source code of site with c#.
i try with this code,get source code but not completed code of site.
For Exapmle:**this [site](https://www.digikala.com/Product/DKP-133006/%DA%AF%D9%88%D8%B4%D9%8A-%D9%85%D9%88%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%8A%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%BE%D9%84-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%84-iPhone-SE-%D8%B8%D8%B1%D9%81%D9%8A%D8%AA-16-%DA%AF%D9%8A%DA%AF%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%8A%D8%AA)** for show **price(قیمت)** and **other options(guaranty(گارانتی),color(رنگ))**,use the **script** and **ajax** .this information exist in **inspect** but not exist in page source.

**use this:**

`vs2013 v12 update4`

`Selenium.WebDriver.3.0.1\lib\net40\WebDriver.dll`

**try this codes:**

```
       link_Pagesource = link_Pagesource.Replace("http://", "https://");
        HttpWebRequest URL_pageSource = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link_Pagesource);
        URL_pageSource.Timeout = 360000;
        URL_pageSource.ReadWriteTimeout = 360000;
 using (WebResponse MyResponse_PageSource = URL_pageSource.GetResponse())
      {
           str_PageSource = new StreamReader(MyResponse_PageSource.GetResponseStream(), 
          System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
          pagesource1 = str_PageSource.ReadToEnd();

        }
```

**and**

```
 IWebDriver _driver;
    _driver = new ChromeDriver();

   _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(link_Pagesource);
    pagesource1 = _driver.PageSource;
   _driver.Close();
   _driver.Quit();
```

and :

```
               driver5 = new ChromeDriver();
                driver5.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(500));
                IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver5;
                string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return document.body.innerHTML;");

                string title2 = (string)js.ExecuteScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML;");

                IList<IWebElement> all = new List<IWebElement>();
                IList<IWebElement> divtag = driver5.FindElements(By.XPath("//div"));
                IList<IWebElement> labelstag = driver5.FindElements(By.XPath("//label"));

                String[] allText = new String[all.Count];
                int i = 0;
                foreach (IWebElement element in divtag)
                {
                    allText[i++] = element.Text;
                }

                String[] allText1 = new String[all.Count];
                int y = 0;
                foreach (IWebElement element in labelstag)
                {
                    allText[y++] = element.Text;
                }
```

For me all data is important,exist important data in the load js or ajax.

not code this section of website in pagesource got.

[pic of site,selected by draq important data for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7eMN.jpg)

[pic for price(قیمت)** and **other options(guaranty(گارانتی),color(رنگ))**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0leEr.png)

[elements and div for u](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX94A.png)

this link is source completed save but not access with c# :

http://localhost:5049/session/0fba2e005ffd1efeb39a9a999bfbb2d5/source

error timeout 60 second

Comment: `_driver.PageSource` will give you the current state. So if an AJAX runs after 500ms and changes the page, you won't have the data. Insert some sleep and then capture page source and see if you get what is needed

Comment: can u edit my code or refrence? thanks for help

Comment: @TarunLalwani please check my pic in question for clear my question,if not clear for u.

Comment: the past month get your site very good and very fast and complete. this site change the structure of site and i could not get now.

Answer (score 1):

Try below :-

```
IWebDriver driver; // assume assigned elsewhere
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return document.body.innerHTML;");
```

OR

```
IWebDriver driver; // assume assigned elsewhere
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML;");
```

Just print the title string variable

Use below code to print all div and labels

```
IList<IWebElement> divtag = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div"));
IList<IWebElement> labelstag = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//label"));

foreach (IWebElement element in divtag)
{
    element.Text;
}

foreach (IWebElement element in labelstag)
{
    element.Text;
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: test but not codes of important data in page source,please view of pic in my question.

Comment: can you specify the tag in which they all are present? like div, a etc

Comment: please wait for specify

Comment: please check pic in my question , price and elemnt for u

Comment: As per image it appears that the text present in label and div. It will be better if you can upload your HTML DOM to somewhere. so we can see page source for more info.

Comment: what is all? error for `all` String[] allText = new String[all.Count]; not exist

Comment: IList<IWebElement> all = new List<IWebElement>(); ?

Comment: I am java guys you can try something in c#

Comment: please check my question and read your solution in c#,correct? count for me is 0

Comment: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:5049/session/0fba2e005ffd1efeb39a9a999bfbb2d5/source timed out after 60 seconds.

Comment: I have updated my code and remove string .. just use element.Text;

Comment: element.text erorr.

Comment: C# error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198947/how-to-get-text-from-each-cell-of-an-html-table